# How can I keep specific chunks loaded with command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm looking for a way to keep specific chunks loaded with a command block loop or permanent command, because I have a large world with lots of redstone and I have to keep moving with the redstone signals so that they finish their signal. This is for Bukkit MC 1.9.2 with multiple worlds loaded on it.

Comment: Do you want to do this with just command blocks or with a Bukkit plugin?

Comment: There may be mods/plugins for this. I don't think you can do it with command blocks, though the dev team should definitely add that. Try this: https://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/chunkloader/

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/125290/can-i-use-a-hopper-loop-as-a-chunk-loader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've already built your redstone contraptions. The simplest thing you can do, since spawn points keep the world loaded in a 128 block radius, is to use the `/setworldspawn` command to move the world spawn to the middle of your redstone devices. This should be enough to keep at least one device working at all times.

Unfortunately, if your device is unusually large, you cannot use command blocks to move the worldspawn along with the current. According to the wiki:

> new spawn chunks won't be loaded by this command until a player moves within range.

If you do have multiple or large devices that need to remain operational, I might recommend using bots/alts to keep the necessary chunks loaded.

Sources:

- [r/minecraft](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/2pz6lt?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3): Is there a way to keep a chunk loaded on SMP?
- [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/22114/115560): How far can redstone current travel?
- [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.fandom.com/Commands/setworldspawn): Commands/setworldspawn

Comment: Also, regarding the worldspawn solution, it's worth noting that the redstone radius is a bit smaller than the worldspawn radius:
http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Spawn/Multiplayer_details#Constantly_loaded_chunks

Additionally, bots or alts may be necessary anyways, since when the last player leaves the dimension, the redstone may stop working:
http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Spawn_chunk#Spawn_chunks_and_other_dimensions

Assuming the gamerule `spectatorsGenerateChunks` is still set to `true`, your bots/alts can remain despawned while keeping the chunks loaded.

Comment: Is a trick with hoppers aiming through chunk border, thus loading next chunk (so they know if they can transfer), fixed in 1.9?

Comment: Not sure, honestly. Also not sure if aiming hoppers through portals keeps the universe loaded when the last player exits in 1.9. I'm not really a hopper-kinda-guy. The changelog doesn't mention anything about these items being changed, though, so I don't see why they shouldn't work.

Comment: I have recently heard from an independent source that aiming hoppers from the spawn chunk through the chunk border is currently a functional game mechanic, even when the last player exits the realm.

Answer (score -1):

You can turn your render distance up or go afk with your player ingame. Sorry, but that is the best, and simplest answer. There is no plugin for it, as minecraft mechanics do not allow it.